# Framer-Motion Exit Animation not firing on outer parent

Tags: javascript, animation, framer-motion, framerjs, react-animations

Using `AnimatePresence` here from `framer-motion` and the exit animation of the outer parent does not seem to fire.

The enter animations fire for all 3 elements. For the exit animaions, only the 2 children's exit animations fire. The outer parent vanishes with no exit animation. What gives?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dusty-badger-forked-yu5xm?file=/components/overlay.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a confirmed bug with `transition: { when: "afterChildren" }` and has been fixed in [framer-motion@3.5.3](https://github.com/framer/motion/commit/02b334bc2f2f3dba43d5f01ebdd7bc4a1e195f58).